# Java how to create an enum that contains the element "TIMESTAMP(6)"

Tags: java

I'm trying to build an advanced search function in an app that builds a query based on a dataType.

My potential dataTypes are `FLOAT, NUMBER, CHAR, VARCHAR2, DATE, TIMESTAMP(6)`

I'm trying to "code out of my shell" and instead of using an ArrayList to store the values, i was going to try and use `enum` since i only have these 6 values and they never change.

`TIMESTAMP(6)` is giving me a hard time because of the parenthesis.

How can i declare an enum value `TIMESTAMP(6)`?

Currently the snippet below gives me the error: the constructor TableBacking.dataTypeOptions(int) is undefined.

```
public enum dataTypeOptions {
    FLOAT, NUMBER, CHAR, VARCHAR2, DATE, TIMESTAMP(6)
};
```

Comment: I think the problem is the name of `VARCHAR2` and `TIMESTAMP(6)`. If you can think of a better abstraction such as `CODE` (instead of `VARCHAR2`) and `AUDIT_TIMESTAMP` (intead of `TIMESTAMP(6)`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The enum constant names need to be valid identifiers. So you could call it `TIMESTAMP_6` for example.

If you later need a string representation that returns `TIMESTAMP(6)` you can use a String constructor in your enum to define that value.

It could look like this:

```
public enum dataTypeOptions {

    FLOAT, NUMBER, CHAR, VARCHAR2, DATE, TIMESTAMP_6("TIMESTAMP(6)");
    private String stringRepresentation;

    dataTypeOptions() { //default behaviour, use the enum constant identifier
        this.stringRepresentation = this.name();
    }

    dataTypeOptions(String s) {
        this.stringRepresentation = s;
    }

    public String getStringRepresentation() {
        return stringRepresentation;
    }

};
```

Comment: Great answer, but after seeing this, i'm thinking that it might be much simpler to just use an ArrayList with predefined values.